# Using common database for multiple developers in local environment gets slow

Tags: database, 9, caching, performance

When use the **common database to develop in local environment for multiple developers** in one **Drupal 9** project is getting too slow. This issue occurs on Drupal sites only, others (**Wordpress, Laravel, Codeigniter and slim**) are working fine with the same database from the server and found that not an network and server issue. In our scenario, we want to use a common database for multiple developers in our local environment for a Drupal 9 project. We may clear the cache frequently during the development process.Can you give me any suggestions for achieving this process?

Used the common database from host server to develop in local environment for multiple developers in one Drupal 9 project. But it gets slow when loading (for ex. doing CRUD operation, cache clear and etc).

Could any one provide the suggestion to implement the common database for multiple developers in local environment Drupal sites?

Comment: What is the database type and version?

Comment: Drupal is not designed for multiple uncoordinated code bases to be sharing a database instance. It may work for you at times, but it is quite unusual.

Comment: Local databases don't matter because 99% of Drupal is controlled from configuration anyway. "Sharing" a database to do development in doesn't make sense and is an extreme risk. In fact frequently clearing the cache is probably what makes it slow for everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It is not clear what exactly *the common database to develop in local environment for multiple developers* would mean. Does that mean developers are using the same database for different test sites? Do they all access the same database that is used for a single Drupal instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a [documented base configuration](https://www.drupal.org/node/259580) for performance with MySQL. It is too long to quote here. It includes instructions for next steps if needed.

Comment: sorry but it is not working in our case

Comment: Can you confirm you tried every single suggestion in the article, including all the sample configurations? Also as I mentioned above, Drupal is not designed for multiple uncoordinated code bases to be sharing a database instance. They can share a database server, but if they are using the same database instance you can expect problems.